# Analysis (Absolute Value )

Tags: analysis

The question is let $a \in \mathbb{R} $  does not contain 0. Prove that $|a+\frac{1}{a}| \ge 2$. I have no idea how to start this problem and any help on it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is an element not a set. So saying it does not contain $0$ makes no sense. Also, if $a$ is positive, what can you say about $\frac{1}{a}?$ If $a$ is negative, what can you say about $\frac{1}{a}$? Therefore, reduce the problem to $a$>0, and I think you can handle it from here... or at least start here, if you show work and can't get more help will likely come.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\left|a+\frac 1 a\right|\ge2\iff a^2+1\ge2|a|\iff (|a|-1)^2\ge0\;\text{which's true}$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume for a moment that $a >0$, just to make the intuition clearer. Then you want to prove

$$
a + \frac{1}{a} \geq 2
$$

which is true if and only if

$$
a^2 + 1 \geq 2a
$$

i.e. if

$$
a^2 - 2a + 1 = (a - 1)^2 \geq 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is enough to consider the case $a>0$. Also note that for $x,y$ non negative, $x+y\geq 2\sqrt{xy}$.